# C# reading lines matching a criteria in a way similar to preg_match

Tags: c#, preg-match, match, readfile

I am a tempting to create a simple inventory system and I was thinking to use a txt file to store the data. My setup is a forum with a listbox and a text box.
 The list box is supposed to list all items in the inventory and the textbox is to list item stats when it is selected.

My formating in the txt is:

```
[[itemname

stat

stat

...
```

How do I select the lines starting with `[[?`? Is there a functionality similar to php's preg_match?

Comment: this is what DATABASES were designed for. also what have you done besides posting something about what you want.. please show us what you have tried on your own.. first..

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
string s = "your content";
if (s.StartsWith ("[["))
{

}
```

For more details, check 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396